# Sublime Anaconda "Autoformatting failed, buffer not changed"

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I just installed `Anaconda` on `Sublime`, when I save it says `autoformatting failed, buffer not changed`, therefore it will not autoformat because of that error. Even though I have autoformatting set to true in my user settings. What do I do? I Tried changing

```
"auto_formatting_timeout": 1,
```

to

```
"auto_formatting_timeout": 5,
```

and still nothing.

When I look up my file path on `CMD` using `"Where Python"` it states

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

and I am saving it under anaconda sublime user settings as

```
C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
```

any help?

Comment: I don't think that message means the file wasn't saved, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Sorry, what im saying is it will not autoformat because of that error. even though i have autoformatting set to true in my user settings.

Comment: maybe if you run `Sublime` in console/terminal then it will display some error messages which could help. Maybe there is bug in code which format it and then changing `timeout` can't help.